# TYPO3: hide 'Plugin Mode' and 'Record Storage Page' in a plugin

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I was wondering if it is possible to hide both the 'Plugin Mode' and 'Record Storage Page' sections (pallets?) inside a plugin.

When I only have one setting in my flexform configuration, it is almost overlooked when having these two large sections visible. In a lot of cases it would be great to remove such 'clutter' from the plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is possible by changing the TCA.
Add this to `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist']['news_pi1'] 
  = 'recursive,select_key,pages'
```

of course you need to change `news_pi1` to the plugin configuration name of yours.

I took the example from my extension [news](https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Works like a charm!