# TYPO3 How to remove the header section from my plugins backend form

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have an extension with a plugin to render a list in the front-end. I don't want the header of the plugin to be rendered in the front-end nor want I that my customer is bothered with it in the beck-end.

[image: the header section must go]

How can I make it disappear? How can I find the place where it is defined how the back-end form for the plugin is rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: just remove the headers tab and palettes from the types array in your TCA....

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Isn't the TCA only about  the tx_extkey_domain_model_record tables and not about the records in tt_content?

Comment: TCA defines **all* field, including the core tables. For your plugin, you are already extending `tt_content` TCA by registering the plugin. This way you add a new `list_type`.
Via `subtypes_excludelist`, it's possible to remove fields from the 'list' type of tt_content in special cases of your list_type:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Types/Index.html?highlight=subtypes_excludelist#subtypes-excludelist

Answer (score 3):

Add in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist'][<your_plugin_signature>] = 'header,header.types,subheader,header_link,header_position,header_layout,date';
```

Answer (score 1):

The backend fields can be configured via the `TCEFORM` section of your Page TSConfig.

E.g. to disable the header field of your plugin:
`TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.tx_yourextkey.header.disabled = 1`

See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html) for more details.

Regarding frontend rendering: normally you don't need to change anything regarding your disabled fields because they are not rendered anyways.

But if you need to adjust something, check your TypoScript configuration in the TypoScript Object browser and search for this part (or similar):
`tt_content.list.20.extkey_pi1`

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your time! I tried your TCEFORM line and I can see it registering in the Info-panel. But it's not removing the the header section. I took my extension key from the ExtensionBuilder.json and tried with and without tx_. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `types`-field of `tt_content` is `CType`. *All* (normal) plugins are of CType 'list'. This solution can only be used for *CTypes*, not for certain plugins (which is the field `list_type`).

Comment: `TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.tx_news.header.disabled = 1` doesn't works ether. I try to corner the problem like this: `TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.list.disabled = 1` removes all lists header but not the sub-header and link. Just like @JulianHofmann said

Comment: With the `TCEFORM` stuff, you can only disable **fields**. For hiding the whole block of fields, you have to hide **each** field within the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.list.disabled = 1
TCEFORM.tt_content.subheader.types.list.disabled = 1
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_link.types.list.disabled = 1
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_position.types.list.disabled = 1
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.types.list.disabled = 1
```

achieves what I want to do with the huge drawback of having no list with a heading. So this might be an answer but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the subtypes_excludelist is helpful for you. This is often used to remove some fields for plugins but I never tried to exclude all the header fields.

[TYPO3: hide 'Plugin Mode' and 'Record Storage Page' in a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386018/typo3-hide-plugin-mode-and-record-storage-page-in-a-plugin/39387488)

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Types/Index.html#subtypes-excludelist